# expandablelistview with multiple textviews

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have an expandablelistview, that the parent has 4 textviews and the children, 4 textviews also.

I know how can I populate if I have only 1 element on the parent and 1 on the child, but with 4 I don't.

I think I must have all my data in separate arrayLists.

```
  numerosServicios = new ArrayList<String>();
    profesiones = new ArrayList<String>();
    direcciones = new ArrayList<String>();
    fechasCaduca = new ArrayList<String>();
    tipos = new ArrayList<String>();
    diasEnCurso = new ArrayList<String>();
    fechasProximasCitas = new ArrayList<String>();
    estados = new ArrayList<String>();
```

But I don't know how I should make the adapter. I see this code but I don't understand it.

Anyone has a example please? Thanks

**EDIT**

I found a "solution":

```
    private List<? extends List<? extends Map<String, ?>>> creaListadeHijos() {
                    ArrayList resultado_hijo = new ArrayList();
                    for(int i=0;i<=ArrayServicios.size();i++){
                        HashMap hijo = new HashMap();
                        hijo.put("tipo", tipos.get(i));
                        hijo.put("diasEnCurso", diasEnCurso.get(i));
                        hijo.put("estado", estados.get(i));
                        hijo.put("fechaProCita", fechasProximasCitas.get(i));
                        resultado_hijo.add(hijo);
                    }

                    return (List)resultado_hijo;    }

                private List<? extends Map<String, ?>> creaListaDeGrupos() {


                    ArrayList resultado_padre = new ArrayList();
                    for(int i=0;i<=ArrayServicios.size();i++){
                        HashMap padre = new HashMap();
                        padre.put("numero_servicio", numerosServicios.get(i));
                        padre.put("profesion", profesiones.get(i));
                        padre.put("direccion", direcciones.get(i));
                        padre.put("fecha_cad", fechasCaduca.get(i));
                        resultado_padre.add(padre);
                    }

                    return (List)resultado_padre;
                }
SimpleExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                        contexto,
                        creaListaDeGrupos(),
                        R.layout.linea_padre,
                        new String[] { "numero_servicio","profesion","direccion","fecha_cad" },
                        new int[] { R.id.tvServicio,R.id.tvProfesion,R.id.tvDireccion,R.id.tvDiasEnCurso},      
                        creaListadeHijos(), 
                        R.layout.linea_hija,    
                        new String[] { "tipo", "diasEnCurso","estado","fechaProCita" }, 
                        new int[] { R.id.tvTipo , R.id.tvDiasEnCurso, R.id.tvEstado, R.id.tvFechaProximaCita}   
                        );

                setListAdapter( expListAdapter );
                registerForContextMenu(getExpandableListView());
```

Comment: how about creating a bean of all your data and then a single arraylist of it...

Comment: But making this i only need one textview per row or group?I want to use the 4 textviews

Comment: make your custom class which contain String variables. then make a arraylist of that class.

Comment: that is what i meant by bean same as what Zaz means,....